# Exception with objects in an array

Tags: java

I have a mini-project and a lot of classes. I created an exception for a field, it doesn't work

```
public C(..., int yearX, ...) throws InitException {
        if (year == 2000) {
            ...
            year = yearX;
            ...
        } else
            throw new InitAnneeEC();
    }
```

Comment: Might be a little easier if it's in English . . but you also should make the code smaller, i.e narrow down where the issue is

Comment: I think you don't understand the purpose of exceptions. If you throw an exception in a method or constructor, that method or constructor exits immediately. If it's a constructor, the object construction fails, and it's as if the object was never created. It sounds to me like that's what you're complaining about -- but actually, that's exactly how it's *supposed* to work, and in fact, that's the only reason to ever throw an exception from a constructor: if you want to cancel creation of the object.

Comment: When an exception is thrown from the constructor of an object, it's expected that it will not be initialised. What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your constructor you compare `year` but you don't set it's value first, so the exception always happen.

```
    public C(..., int yearX, ...) throws InitException {
        if (year == 2000) {
            ...
            year = yearX;
            ...
        } else
            throw new InitAnneeEC();
    }
```

When you doing `if (year == 2000)` actually it's used the default value: 0, so the comparison always false.
I guess you want to set `anneeEC` value with `anneeE` value.

Try to change your code like this:

```
    public C(..., int yearX, ...) throws InitException {
        year = yearX;
        if (year == 2008) {
            ...
        } else
            throw new InitException();
    }
```